# can't get firebase authenticated user info qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've tried Firebase C++ on Qt android app. So far I can get all the basic steps working as the message showing (`GsE9xxxxxx` is my user id from Firebase console)

> FirebaseAuth: Notifying listeners about user ( GsE9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxi1
>   ).
>
> FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
>
> FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.

However, the next step that I'm trying to get current user info, the app crashed! Here's my snippet

```
Future<User*> result =
        m_auth->SignInWithEmailAndPasswordLastResult();

if (result.status() == firebase::kFutureStatusComplete) {
      if (result.error() == kAuthErrorNone) {
          User* user = *result.result();
        if(user != nullptr)
        {
            qDebug() << "Sign in succeeded for email " << user->email().c_str();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "User -> nullptr";
        }
      } else
      {
        qDebug() << "Sign in failed with error " << result.error_message();
        return false;
      }
```

The part that failed is the line to access the user info

```
user->email()
```

And yes, I've tried other fields (`display_name`, `uid`), but all crashed at this line. I'm sure that the user variable is not giving nullptr but I don't know what inside the user variable there that causes the crash.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce this issue. Try the latest version of the C++ SDK.  Firebase devs have fixed similar issues recently.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll check the latest version and see if there's anything related to my issue.